# Wordpress. Изменение разметки the_meta();

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Мне нужно сделать *акордеон* из произвольных полей `the_meta();`. Но стандартный вызов создает разметку такого вида:

```
<ul class='post-meta'>
  <li><span class='post-meta-key'>your_key:</span> your_value</li>
  <li><span class='post-meta-key'>your_key:</span> your_value</li>
</ul>
```

То есть `your_value` не выделено никаким тегом, что мне не подходит. Сам вывод функции `the_meta();` реализован в файле `wp-includes/post-template.php`

```
function the_meta() {
    if ( $keys = get_post_custom_keys() ) {
        echo "<ul class='post-meta'>\n";
        foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) {
            $keyt = trim($key);
            if ( is_protected_meta( $keyt, 'post' ) )
                continue;
            $values = array_map('trim', get_post_custom_values($key));
            $value = implode($values,', ');

            echo apply_filters( 'the_meta_key', "<li><span class='post-meta-key'>$key:</span> $value</li>\n", $key, $value );
        }
        echo "</ul>\n";
    }
}
```

Править этот файл тоже не подходит, чтоб при обновлении не слетело.

Как добавить фильтр или action, чтоб `your_value` обернуть в `span` или `p`?

Answer (score 1):

А если попробовать по другому к примеру

```
<ul>
<?php 
    $custom_fields = get_post_meta($post->ID,'',false);
            foreach ( $custom_fields as $key => $value ){
                    $theValue = $value[0];
                    $i=$key;
                    echo "<li><span class='post-meta-key'>".$key ."</span><span class='post-meta-value'>" . $theValue . "</span></li>";
            }?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Всё так, но в массив выводит еще _edit_last, _edit_lock, _thumbnail_id. Не пойму почему...

Comment: @Юрий Рымарь вы не писали что это ненадо выводить вот так я эту проблему решил 
<pre>switch ($i) {
  case $i != preg_match('/_/',$key):
  break; 
  case $i =='/*сюда вносяся тоже не нужные мета поля*/':
  break;
  default:
   echo "<tr><td>".$key ."</td><td>" . $theValue . "</td></tr>";
  break;
  } </pre>
вместо echo в вашем примере.

Comment: <pre> убирите только :) .

Answer (score -1):

Используйте  `get_post_custom_keys();`, а обертку создайте сами.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?